# VB - System.NullReferenceException - LINQ to SQL with datestamps

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2012

I have an SQL DB with a table (Beko) where each record contains a datestamp (of data type date) for the date it was created. I am trying to populate a calendar control (calBeko) so that each day that a record exists is highlighted.

I have declared the following in my page class to hold the days that contain a record

```
Private days As IEnumerable(Of DateTime) = Nothing
```

I am then using the following in the Page_PreRender event to create and array of the days that contain a record:

```
Dim startDate, endDate, baseDate As DateTime

    If calBeko.VisibleDate.Year <> 1 Then
        baseDate = calBeko.VisibleDate
    Else
        baseDate = DateTime.Now
    End If

    startDate = New DateTime(baseDate.Year, baseDate.Month, 1)
    endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)

    Dim dc As New BekoDataContext
    Dim days = (From Beko In dc.Bekos _
               Where Beko.DateStamp <= endDate And _
               Beko.DateStamp >= startDate _
               Order By Beko.DateStamp _
               Select New DateTime(Beko.DateStamp.Year, _
                                   Beko.DateStamp.Month, _
                                   Beko.DateStamp.Day) Distinct).ToArray()
```

I am then using the calBeko_DayRender event to highlight the days where a record exists:

```
For Each d In days
        If d.Day = e.Day.Date.Day AndAlso _
            d.Month = e.Day.Date.Month Then
            e.Cell.CssClass = "ajax_calendar_checkday"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Problem is when I run the page I am getting a System.NullReferenceException on the following line:

```
For Each d In days
```

It seems that no values are being assigned to 'days'. I have checked the table and there are valid records in there so I assume my code is wrong. Apologies if this is vague or I haven't provided enough info, I am very new to this.

Comment: So what is in `From be In dc.Bekos` why do you have to `ToArray()` it? Why not `ToList()`? With ToList you can check if it has anything it in by the `Any()` method which returns bool. Alternatively check if it is `Nothing` before doing anything with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jeremy, I noticed the 'from be in dc.Bekos' is wrong, it should be 'from Beko in dc.Bekos'. Beko is a single of Bekos in my Beko.dbml. I changed the 'be' to 'Beko' but I'm still getting no value assigned to 'days'. I'll edit my post accordingly as I have LINQ to SQL statements working correctly on other pages using 'Beko in dc.Bekos'

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on this `Dim daysList = (From b In dc.Bekos 
 Where b.DateStamp <= endDate And _b.DateStamp >= startDate _select b).ToList()` and see what is inside the `List<Becko>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new local variable `days` in your code

```
Dim days = (From Beko In dc.Bekos _
```

instead of assigning the result of your query to your class variable `days`. Therefore is days `Nothing` in your `calBeko_DayRender` method and you get the Exception.

Your code should be

```
days = (From Beko In dc.Bekos _
               Where Beko.DateStamp <= endDate And _
               Beko.DateStamp >= startDate _
               Order By Beko.DateStamp _
               Select New DateTime(Beko.DateStamp.Year, _
                                   Beko.DateStamp.Month, _
                                   Beko.DateStamp.Day) Distinct).ToArray()
```

Comment: Superb, works a treat. Such a basic mistake to make as well. Thank you very much